# How to save the file path to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried and have looked at StackOverflow and the other posts are not answering my questions. This is a unique question. How can I get the path of the most recently uploaded file saved to a variable so it can be used later?

Code:

```
var pathtocheck = "C:\Users\user1\Downloads";


var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');


var getMostRecent = function (dir, cb) {
    var dir = path.resolve(dir);
    var files = fs.readdir(dir, function (err, files) {
        var sorted = files.map(function(v) {
            var filepath = path.resolve(dir, v);
            return {
                name:v,
                time:fs.statSync(filepath).mtime.getTime()
            }; 
        })
        .sort(function(a, b) { return b.time - a.time; })
        .map(function(v) { return v.name; });

        if (sorted.length > 0) {
            
            cb(null, sorted[0]);
    
        } else {
            cb('Y U NO have files in this dir?');
        

        }
    })
}

await getMostRecent(pathtocheck, function (err, recent) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log(recent);

});

var lastdownloadedimage = ;
```

Comment: I can't figure out what is wrong with your code. I took a look at it and everything seems to be ok. What kind of issue did you find with it? I don't know what is the project about, but if you are working in a database, maybe save file names and date "on upload" could be a good alternative.

Comment: @MarceloJForclaz Trying to see how I can edit to getMostRecent() to return the file path of the most recent image in the folder. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With callbacks, you have to write your code in the callback passed to getMostRecent, so

```js
// Note: awaiting this takes no effect unless getMostRecent returns a promise.
getMostRecent(pathtocheck, function (err, recent) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log(recent);

    var lastdownloadedimage = recent;
    // Or just directly use `recent`
});
```

Or,

Async-await and Promise can also solve your issue, though I'm not sure how much you're familiar with them.

You can use Promisified version of file system API in Node.js v10 or above, by `require('fs').promises` instead of `require('fs')` (Documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api))

Decalration of the functions like this:

```js
// Also it's a good practice to use `const` or `let`, instead of `var`

const pathtocheck = "C:\Users\user1\Downloads";

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

// Decalre the function with `async` to use `await` in it
const getMostRecent = async function (dir) {
    dir = path.resolve(dir);
    const files = await fsp.readdir(dir)
    
    const sorted = files.map(function(v) {
        const filepath = path.resolve(dir, v);
        return {
            name:v,
            time:fs.statSync(filepath).mtime.getTime()
            // maybe you can use fsPromises.stat here
        }; 
    })
    .sort(function(a, b) { return b.time - a.time; })
    .map(function(v) { return v.name; });
        
    if (sorted.length > 0) {
        return sorted[0];
    } else {
        // Now you have no callbacks, so there are two options to return the error state.
        //   1. Throw an Error with an error message
        //   2. Return a special value such as `null` or `false`, which you can track it.
    }
}; // <-- perhaps you need place a semicolon here.
```

And you call the function in async [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), wrapping anonymous async function to use `await`

```js
(async function() {
  const lastdownloadedimage = await getMostRecent(pathtocheck);
  console.log(lastdownloadedimage)
})();
```

Or use `Promise.then`:

```js
getMostRecent(pathtocheck).then(function(recent) {
    var lastdownloadedimage = recent;
    // Again, you can just directly use `recent`
})
```